# Does Dinero support parsing a money amount in a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dinero.js

I have a money amount in a string, eg `'5.0'`, `'1.1'`

We're using dinero.js to handle money.  Is there a way for Dinero to accept a string like the above
and return a money object of the equivalent amount (the currency should be one we specify, eg GBP or USD)?  In the above examples, it would return £5, £1.10.

If this is supported, how?

Thanks